# $C^2$ convergence of smooth functions in manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Matsumoto's "An Introduction to Morse Theory" the author defines a $(C^2,\varepsilon)$-approximation of a smooth function $g:M\to\mathbb{R}$ defined on a compact smooth manifold in the following way :

Take a finite atlas $\{(U_1,\varphi_1),\ldots,(U_s,\varphi_s)\}$ and a family of compacts $K_1,\ldots,K_s$ such that $K_i\subset U_i$ for every $i=1,\ldots,s$ and $$M=K_1\cup\ldots\cup K_s.$$ We say that $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ is a $(C^2,\varepsilon)$-approximation of $g$ if the following conditions holds over $K_i$ for every $i=1,\ldots,s$ :
$$|f(p)-g(p)|<\varepsilon,\quad \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(p)-\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_j}(p)\right|<\varepsilon,\quad \left|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}(p)-\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x_j\partial x_k}(p)\right|<\varepsilon,$$ for all $j,k=1,\ldots,m$.

This definition is dependent of the choice of the finite atlas so I would like to substitute it for a notion of $C^2$- convergence of sequences of functions $f_n:M\to\mathbb{R}$, independent of the choice of the finite atlas. Does anybody know such a definition ?

Comment: First, although the definition of $(C^2,\epsilon)$-approximation depends on the atlas, the definition of $C^2$ convergence does not. A sequence of functions converges with respect to one atlas if and only if it converges with respect to another. If you prefer a definition that does not mention atlases, then you can fix a smooth Riemannian metric on $M$ and define the $C^2$ norm of a function $f$ as $\|f\|_\infty + \|df\|_\infty + \|\nabla^2f\|_\infty$.

Comment: @Deane could you explain me how the norms in the last expressions are defined and which is the role of the Riemannian metric ?

Comment: For each $x \in M$, $df(x) \in T^*_xM$ and $\nabla^2f(x) \in S^2T^*M$ are tensors, and the Riemannian metric, i.e., an inner product on $T_xM$, induces natural (i.e., independent of coordinates) inner products on tensors. So $|df(x)|$ and $|\nabla^2f(x)|$ are well-defined. You can then define $\|df\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in M} |df(x)|$ and $\|\nabla^2f\|_\infty = \sup_{x \in M} |\nabla^2f(x)|$